# Inconsistent packages between Jupyter Notebook and Conda Command Line

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I just installed PyTorch and am trying to use it in my Jupyter Notebook. In the notebook, when I run `conda list`, I see the following:

```
# packages in environment at /Users/whoiam/opt/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0  
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
anaconda                  2019.10                  py37_0  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.7                    py37_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.3                      py_0 
...
python                    3.7.4                h359304d_1  
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0  
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_13  
python.app                2                        py37_9  
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0 
...
```

But, in the command line of my terminal, I see this:

```
(base) whoiam@MacBook-Pro Downloads % conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/whoiam/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0  
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
anaconda                  2019.10                  py37_0  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.7                    py37_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.3                      py_0  
...
python                    3.7.4                h359304d_1  
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0  
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_13  
python.app                2                        py37_9  
pytorch                   1.3.0                   py3.7_0    pytorch
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0  
...
```

I have a few questions:

1. Why is one environment at `whoiam/opt/anaconda3` and the other at `whoiam/anaconda3`?
2. Should I be updating the Jupyter Notebook or the Command Line path?
3. How do I update either path?
4. Through which should I install packages to avoid this issue?

Comment: Can you please run `conda env list` on the conda command line and share the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running jupyter notebook in (base) Command Line solved my problem:

Execute `jupyter notebook` in base.

Answer (score 0):

You should create and use one conda enviroment other than `(base)`.

After creating it, you should activate this env, through anaconda navigator or with `source activate yourenvname`. You will see something like:

`(yourenvname) whoiam@MacBook-Pro Downloads`

In the terminal, if your enviroment, with the name yourenvname is activated.

Only after doing this, you can install your packages via `pip install`  in the terminal and then open you jupyter notebook, or directly install your packages in the jupyter notebook. By activating the env you ensure that all your packages are in the same and only directory.

Comment: Running `jupyter notebook` in (base) Command Line solved my problem. But why are "Applications on base (root)" different than "Applications on anaconda3" if anaconda3 is on root?